# Get Super Class from TypeElement without Generic?

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

I have a class:

```
public class StartPagePresenter extends AbstractPresenter<String> {
...
}
```

Using Java Annotation Processing I got the `TypeElement` of the class:

```
TypeElement startPagePresenterType = // get the TypeElement of StartPagePresenter
```

Now I need to get the super class which is done with:

```
startPagePresenterType.getSuperclass();
```

Then I tried to check if the super class has the correct type with:

```
if ( !startPagePresenterType.getSuperclass().toString().equals(
     AbstractPresenter.class.getCanonicalName()) ) {
 ...
}
```

Here is the problem: `AbstractPresenter.class.getCanonicalName()` leads to:

```
core.mvp.AbstractPresenter
```

and `startPagePresenterType.getSuperclass().toString()` leads to:

```
core.mvp.AbstractPresenter<java.lang.String>
```

When you compare these Strings they are never equal although the super classes are the same.

**How can I get the super class from `startPagePresenterType.getSuperclass()` without the generic block?**

Comment: Try 

startPagePresenterType.getSuperclass()getCanonicalName().toString().equals(
     AbstractPresenter.class.getCanonicalName()

Comment: getSuperclass does not have a method getCanonicalName

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer:

```
TypeMirror superClassTypeMirror = startPagePresenterType.getSuperclass();
TypeElement superClassTypeElement = 
            (TypeElement)((DeclaredType)superClassTypeMirror).asElement();
```

That's it! `superClassTypeElement`then is the `TypeElement` of the super class.